# How to find variable fields value of a string in Go?

Tags: go

I have two strings:

str1:  "Connection to %s is down and error %d is thrown"

str2:  "Connection to ***DataBase*** is down and error ***401*** is thrown"

In `str2`, with the help of `str1`, I want to find out what are the values in the place of `%s` & `%d` in `str2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `fmt.Sscanf`, which is string and fromat version of `fmt.Scan`:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    str1 := "Connection to %s is down and error %d is thrown"
    str2 := "Connection to DataBase is down and error 401 is thrown"
    var s string
    var d int
    _, err := fmt.Sscanf(str2, str1, &s, &d)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(s, d)
}
```

playground: https://play.golang.org/p/5g5UcrHsunM

Note: It seems you are parsing an error. If the error is from Go, it is highly likely that it provides the data inside the error so you don't need to parse it mannually. And if you have control of the error, it is better to store the data inside.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Actually str1 might have multiple fields with %s & %d.
Can we find out all the %s & %d fields from str1 at the run time and pass them in fmt.Sscanf().